# Sharing folders between Ubuntu(guest) and Windows 7 (host) using VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, file-sharing

I installed Ubuntu guest on a Windows 7 machine using VirtualBox. How can share folders between Ubuntu guest and Windows host? Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/30202/44179

Comment: Have you tried the answer I provided here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81757/shared-folder-virtualization-virtualbox . I can't test since I do not have a windows OS around.

Comment: Please also have a look here for prerequisites: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest

Answer (score 16):

If you get *Permission denied* when accessing the mounted shared folder, run the following command:

```
sudo adduser <yourUsername> vboxsf
```

Substitute `<yourUsername>` by your actual username (e.g. `john` or whichever is yours).

Then restart and you should have full access.

Comment: This definitely needs more upvotes

Comment: Logging out and in sufficed in my case, a full reboot was not needed.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 7 host and Lubuntu 18 guest.

Comment: Or `sudo adduser $USER vboxsf` if you don't know your username or you want a generic command to use in a script

Answer (score 11):

run this on your terminal and everything is going to be fine:

```
sudo mkdir /media/(folder-name-on-linux)
sudo mount -t vboxsf (folder-name-set-on-virtualBox) /media/(folder-name-on-linux)
```

(folder-name-on-linux) will be available easily on your File Manager

PS: That way you won't need to restart your VM ;-)

Comment: This solved it for me. For any future travelers: you may need to run that second command everytime you restart the guest. Does this mean something else is broken? Probably... But it works for me when nothing else did.

Comment: Works for a round. After reboot the sharing is gone.

Answer (score 6):

Close out your guest VM, and then open up the Settings dialog for that VM.  Down near the bottom of the left hand navigation area in that dialog should be an option for shared folders.

You can select which folder(s) on the host machine you want shared with that particular guest VM, whether you want them mounted read-only by the guest, and whether to make them available on boot of the VM.  Once done, restart / restore the guest VM and you should be able to navigate to the new filesystem or folder.

I usually make a new folder inside the 'VirtualBox VMs' folder in my user directory, titled 'Shared' and then share that folder with any guest VMs that need it.  I mount it read-only so that no one machine can b0rk it for the others, and then I can place any necessary files in there that are desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After restarting the guest VM, I opened the "Home" folder on Ubuntu(guest), but I still could not find the "shared" folder created and mounted.

Comment: It is not normal to mount file systems under a user's /home; look for it in the file system.  If it doesn't jump out at you in Nautilus (the file explorer app), it may be under /media/ or /mnt/.  I'm not sitting in front of a box with Virtualbox on it at the moment so I can't be more specific than that for now.  You may need to have Guest Additions installed on the guest VM - other distros like Debian and SuSE auto-install some version of them; Ubuntu does not.

Answer (score 2):

you should make the option of "insert guest  addition CD image" active, from the devices menu, in order to enable shared folder.
the shared folder should appear in the /media.

Answer (score 1):

> Sharing folders between host and guest

- *Step 1*

> Extensions Pack

1. Check if you already installed an extension pack or not?

Steps:   Open VirtualBox ---> Click on File menu ---> Preferences (Ctrl+G) ---> Extensions tab

If you don't find any installed extension pack, go to the VirtualBox download page (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and look for Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack, download and installed it.

(`* Extension Pack must be the same version of your VirtualBox`) [If you don't know what is your's VirtualBox version, just click on Help menu ---> About VirtualBox]

- *Step 2*

> Guest Addition

I.   Start your Virtual Machine

II.  Click on Devices ---> Insert Guest Addition CD image

III. After that, you will see Guest Addition dialog box

IV. Click on Run to start installing VirtualBox Guest Addition

V. Enter your account password and click on Authentication

*[Alternative]*

In case if you don't see Guest Addition dialog box, double click on VirtualBox Guest Addition CD image icon.

[image]

After that, you will see the `cdrom0` folder opened. Right-click in that folder and choose Open In Terminal.

Type in the terminal `sudo su` and enter your account password. Use the `ls` command to show all files of the `cdrom0` folder.

After that, type `chmod +x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` command to change the permission of `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` file.

At last, run the command `sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` to start installing VirtualBox Guest Addition

Now reboot your Virtual Machine.

- *Step 3*

Start your Virtual Machine ---> Click on Devices menu ---> Shared Folders ---> Shared Folder Settings

Now click on Add Folder icon

[image]

Choose your Folder Path, Folder Name will be automatically selected. Put the checkmark on Auto-mount and Make-Permanent. Click on the OK button.

Now reboot again your Virtual Machine.

After reboot, you will find the Shared Folder on your desktop.

> - In case if you are unable to access the content of your Shared Folder, try those following steps.

Open your Terminal. Type `sudo su` then enter your password.

Write the following commands

`sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf mir` (* Instead of `mir` use your account name)

```
sudo chown -R your_account_name:users /media/your_share_folder_name/
```

*Example* `sudo chown -R mir:users /media/sf_Linux_Application/`

Now reboot your Virtual Machine and check the Shared Folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after reading [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793323/how-to-share-ubuntu-16-04-virtualbox-guest-folders) on this site, I discovered that running

```
gksudo nautilus
```

made it work fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.