# How to share Ubuntu 16.04 virtualbox guest folders?

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, nautilus

I updated (fresh install) to 16.04 on my Ubuntu Virtual Machine, I am unable to get permission to access my share folder:

- share folder set to automount in virtualbox.
- account is a member of "vboxsf".

This was not an issue under 14.04, the only way I have found to access the folder from within the guest is to `gksudo nautilus` then I can do whatever.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

**Update**: If I run `ls -l` on the folder, this is what I get:

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 12288 Jun 30 21:37 sf_tnyfgr3 
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 4096 Jun 30 16:45 tnyfgr3
```

Comment: if you do a `ls -l` on `/media` (or wherever your folder is mounted) what is the line of data associated with your folder?

Comment: this is what i get:

Comment: drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 12288 Jun 30 21:37 sf_tnyfgr3
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root    4096 Jun 30 16:45 tnyfgr3

Comment: Hmm, that's the same as mine, which works properly.  So the easy answer is not gonna help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question but the following works for me;

```
sudo add myUsername vboxsf
```

Then restart and you should have full access

```
cd /media/sf_mySharedFolder/
```

Comment: OP said their account is already a member of vboxsf, but other people certainly might find this useful.